# How to access keyboard directly trough I/O ports (in DOS)?

Tags: assembly, input, keyboard, dos

I'm writing a program for DOS and I want to get keyboard input. The thing is that I don't want to get that input using BIOS or DOS. What's the proper way to get keyboard input without using DOS or BIOS? I mean what's the way to get keyboard input in the lowest level of programming using I/O ports. Thanks!

Comment: See http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch there isn't much info about this topic.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10525397/968261).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze thanks, but that's a little bit too hard for me I'd say. I need something easier...

Comment: @Arnas Come on, it's a tiny program. You will learn something from it. And that's the "proper way".

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze thank you! I've analyzed that program, I pretty much understand it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an `inb` instruction on port 0x60 to read the scancode from the keyboard.

```
static inline uint8_t inportb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (ret) : "dN" (port));
    return ret;
}
scancode = inportb(0x60);
```

If you want to know when there's new input you need to setup an interrupt handler to listen for PS/2 interrupts or use USB polling depending on your keyboard.

Comment: Hello, I tried to read port 60h port, but whenever I read it, it instantly returns 28 (scancode of ENTER key). It doesn't even let me to give any input. Maybe I need to clear a buffer? If so, could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @Arnas I believe that if you read from the data port on the keyboard it always contains the last key pressed (which is probably enter). Is it USB or PS/2 keyboard by any chance?

Comment: The one I was using was USB, but I have another one with PS/2.

Comment: For PS/2 you need to setup an interrupt handler for when new data is available. For USB you need to do some extra work which I am not so familiar with currently.