# Check for keypress without blocking if no key was pressed

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm creating an application to view the current time and I created a loop to update the time each second.  The loop looks like this

```
UPDATE:
;The code to be re-executed
JMP UPDATE
```

but I cant end it.  When I use

```
MOV AH, 00H
INT 21H
```

to capture any pressed key, the application stops and waits for a keypress.  I don't want that to happen; the application should go normally and end the loop when the user hits escape

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Look up the DOS system call to poll for input instead of doing a blocking read.  I think it has something, but DOS is obsolete and uninteresting to me, so I don't know what exactly.  Or hook the keyboard interrupt yourself to set a flag (in memory) when ESC is pressed, and check that flag each loop iteration.  BTW, thanks for keeping the question short instead of posting a big irrelevant code-dump.  It's a well-asked question, just not interesting to me personally.  I guess it even deserves an upvote.

Comment: Take a look at `INT 16H` instead. It has a function for "check if a key is pressed".

Comment: SOmething like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524855/how-to-check-keys-status-in-x86-assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever during DOS programming you are looking for some service, have a look at [Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm).

Particularly, keyboard related services fall under the [`int 16h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-16.htm) category.
[`Int 16/AH=01h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) is *CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE* which is exactly what you need: after it returns, the `ZF`<sup>1</sup> is *set*<sup>2</sup> if no keystroke was available; also `AL` and `AH` contain the ASCII and scan code of the key pressed.

Alone however it is not enough as it doesn't remove the keystroke from the buffer, so if the user presses <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>, using *CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE* alone would always return that <kbd>A</kbd> is available.
You can use [`Int 16/AH=00h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm), *GET KEYSTROKE* to read and remove a keystroke from the buffer without echoing it.

You can also use [`Int 21/AH=01h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) to read a character and echo it<sup>3</sup>, **note** that despite what is stated in your question, [`Int 21/AH=00h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2551.htm) is totally unrelated to this task as it is *TERMINATE PROGRAM*.

Finally the ASCII code for <kbd>ESC</kbd> is 27 or 1bh.

---

Here a sample COM program that loops until <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed.

```
BITS 16
ORG 100h

_loop:

 ;
 ; L O O P   S T U F F
 ;

 ;Show a greeting message

 mov ah, 09h
 mov dx, strGreetings
 int 21h



 ;
 ; K E Y S   C H E C K
 ;


 ;Check for a keystroke

 mov ah, 01h
 int 16h
jz _loop                               ;ZF is set if no keystroke available

 ;A keystroke is present, remove it from the buffer
 ;so that we always check the last key pressed by the user

 xor ah, ah
 int 16h

 ;AL = ASCII code     
 ;AH = Scancode

 ;Check the key was ESC

 cmp al, ESC_ASCII_CODE 
jne _loop

 ;
 ; T E R M I N A T I O N
 ;

 mov ax, 4c00h
 int 21h

 ;[ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;   [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;[ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;
 ;D A T A
 ;

 strGreetings db "Hello!", 13, 10, 24h

 ;[ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;   [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;[ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ] [ o ]
 ;
 ;E Q U A L S
 ;

 ESC_ASCII_CODE EQU 27
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The zero flag, you can jump depending on it with `jz/je` (jump if it is set) or `jnz/jne` (jump if it is clear).
<sup>2</sup> Think of this as: Zero was set because there was zero keystrokes.
<sup>3</sup> Though I believe that's not really appropriate for non printable chars.