# assembly: how can I get input from the keyboard while the code keep running?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios, tasm

I want to build a tetris game in assembly (tasm) and I want the cubes to go left/right according to what I press on the keyboard.
I used this code:

```
mov ah, 00h
int 16h ;al=ascii charachter
```

but it waits for the keyboard press and I want it to keep going on and only if I press < or > it'll change, what can I write instead of this?

Comment: You may wish to use AH=1/Int 16h that checks for a keystroke without actually waiting. Then if if there is a keystroke available use AH=0/int 16h to read it. http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm

Comment: Terminology: what you're looking for is a "**non-blocking**" read of a character or keypress.  When an I/O function sleeps (aka blocks) until input is ready, that's called "blocking".  Knowing that terminology let me search and find [Check for keypress without blocking if no key was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38755476) which explains the API Michael Petch suggested.